# Cannot shrink logical volume - mixed messages whether space is available

Tags: lvm

I want to shrink my logical volume (LV)

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/MyOnlyVolumeGroup-MyLogicVolume   59G   23G   35G  40% /MyData
```

but even though there should be 35G space on it, when I command

```
$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/MyOnlyVolumeGroup-MyLogicVolume
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/mapper/MyOnlyVolumeGroup-MyLogicVolume: 258758/3932160 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 6109625/15728640 blocks
```

and ask then for the minimal size, I get

```
$ sudo resize2fs -P /dev/mapper/MyOnlyVolumeGroup-MyLogicVolume
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Estimated minimum size of the filesystem: 5990176
```

Now, I am not sure in what unit this is. At first, I thought it would be the 59GB of the total size, but notice "5 990 176" - sooo... what does that mean?

However, if I assume that it means the 59GB, it would mean I cannot shrink the LV. This would be in line with the fact that the program kvpm (a GUI for LVM management) tells be that

> The file system is already as small as it can be

when I try to tell it to "Reduce logical volume." According to kvpm, space is available just as `df -h` said. Also, my file manager tells me that space is available.

So why do I get this message from `resize2fs`and kvpm and what can I do to shrink the LV?

---

Additional information:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/MyOnlyVolumeGroup-MyLogicVolume
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /MyData
Filesystem UUID:          3a478ae0-2736-414d-b98d-e23195a616e6
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              3932160
Block count:              15728640
Reserved block count:     637401
Free blocks:              9619015
Free inodes:              3673402
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      316
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              2957
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sun Mar 15 18:11:11 2015
Last mount time:          Tue Nov 24 17:58:59 2020
Last write time:          Tue Nov 24 18:01:46 2020
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Nov 24 18:01:46 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          5461 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      d19dddab-633a-4f89-a5b9-6ba7e364d385
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: Assuming a block size of 4096 bytes (check `tune2fs -l`), a minimum size of 5990176 blocks would translate to roughly 22.9 GiB. Unfortunately I can't help with the GUI message. `lvresize --resizefs` should work for ext4 (preferably unmounted)

Comment: @frostschutz: I added the information from `tune2fs -l` into the question. Seems your assumption was right. I read everywhere to use `resizefs` and then `lvreduce` and then `resizefs` again (e.g. at https://blog.shadypixel.com/how-to-shrink-an-lvm-volume-safely). Is your suggested `lvresize --resizefs` doing these three steps at once? (That is what the man seems to imply.) Is that save?

Comment: You should never have to resize2fs twice, but it's often done anyway because of confusion like GiB vs. GB units and programs that refer to block sizes in different ways, like resize2fs itself does... so. It can be done manually if you know what you're doing or you just let lvresize do it for you, this is safe (inasmuch as it can be) for unmounted ext4.